# Build Android Alexa Auto SDK 3.2.1 in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: android, function, sdk, alexa-skills-kit, auto

When I build Android Alexa auto sdk i am facing issues when I run command : ./build.sh android -t androidarm

i get following error

ERROR: rpm-native-1_4.13.90+gitAUTOINC+a8e51b3bb0-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: rpm-native-1_4.13.90+gitAUTOINC+a8e51b3bb0-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile

I am unable to solve this

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04 I run with

```
./builder/build.sh android -t androidx86-64 --android-api 28
```

into

```
| ../../m4-1.4.18/lib/freadahead.c: In function ‘freadahead’:
| ../../m4-1.4.18/lib/freadahead.c:92:3: error: #error "Please port gnulib freadahead.c to your platform! Look at the definition of fflush, fread, ungetc on your system, then report this to bug-gnulib."
|    92 |  #error "Please port gnulib freadahead.c to your platform! Look at the definition of fflush, fread, ungetc on your system, then report this to bug-gnulib."
|       |   ^~~~~
| make[3]: *** [Makefile:1915: freadahead.o] Error 1
| make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| ../../m4-1.4.18/lib/fseeko.c: In function ‘rpl_fseeko’:
| ../../m4-1.4.18/lib/fseeko.c:110:4: error: #error "Please port gnulib fseeko.c to your platform! Look at the code in fseeko.c, then report this to bug-gnulib."
|   110 |   #error "Please port gnulib fseeko.c to your platform! Look at the code in fseeko.c, then report this to bug-gnulib."
|       |    ^~~~~
| make[3]: *** [Makefile:1915: fseeko.o] Error 1
| make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/hannes/git/alexa-auto-sdk/builder/build/tmp-android-28/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/build/lib'
| make[2]: *** [Makefile:1674: all] Error 2
| make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/hannes/git/alexa-auto-sdk/builder/build/tmp-android-28/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/build/lib'
| make[1]: *** [Makefile:1572: all-recursive] Error 1
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hannes/git/alexa-auto-sdk/builder/build/tmp-android-28/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/build'
| make: *** [Makefile:1528: all] Error 2
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/hannes/git/alexa-auto-sdk/builder/build/tmp-android-28/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/temp/log.do_compile.2647129)
ERROR: Task (/home/hannes/oe-core/meta/recipes-devtools/m4/m4-native_1.4.18.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
```